# Why is Python Twarc2 freezing on a large file?

Tags: python, twarc2

I am trying to run Python Twarc hydrate on a very large file of 2,339,076 records but it keeps freezing. I have tried the script on a smaller data set and it works fine. My question is, does Twarc have a maximum number of rows it can process? If so what is it? Do I need to separate my data in to smaller subsections?

I have tried the terminal command:

`twarc2 hydrate 2020-03-22_clean-dataset_csv.csv > hydrated.jsonl`

I have tried it on a smaller file and it works fine

I have tried searching to find whether the is a limit to the number of rows Twarc can process but I can't find an answer.

Comment: Maybe it's consuming all available memory? CSV is line based so can be easily processed in batches, but JSON is not

Comment: OK yes makes sense, is there any way I an fix it do you think? Or should I split my data in to smaller files?

Comment: check your RAM usage, if all ram is full and you must use swap, it can become really slow

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `split`

```
split -n l/10 -d 2020-03-22_clean-dataset_csv.csv subset_
```

This will create 10 files with names like `subset_00`, `subset_01`, etc., each containing approximately one-tenth of the original data.

You can then run Twarc hydrate on each subset separately, like this:

```
twarc2 hydrate subset_00 > hydrated_00.jsonl
```

And then you can read the different `.jsonl` files one by one or look for some way to merge them. (warning, untested as I cannot install twarc2)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but using `split l/10` gives the error `illegal number of chunks.` if I just use the default it gives the error `too many files` I am using MacOS 13.2.1

Comment: It works for a test .csv file on my computer. You can try some of these other options: `CHUNKS may be:
  N       split into N files based on size of input
  K/N     output Kth of N to stdout
  l/N     split into N files without splitting lines/records
  l/K/N   output Kth of N to stdout without splitting lines/records
  r/N     like 'l' but use round robin distribution
  r/K/N   likewise but only output Kth of N to stdout`